# fetch cloud storage bucket last access details

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

How to fetch cloud storage bucket last access details. As of now, I'm seeing we can find only last modified date for bucket and objects. Is there any way to fetch last access details for buckets and objects. Do we need to enable logging for each object to fetch it or Is there any options available?

Answer (score 1):

There are several types of logs you can enable to get this information.

[Cloud Audit Logs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/audit-logs) is the recommended method for generating logs that track API operations performed in Cloud Storage:

- Cloud Audit Logs tracks access on a continuous basis.
- Cloud Audit Logs produces logs that are easier to work with.
- Cloud Audit Logs can monitor many of your Google Cloud services, not
  just Cloud Storage.

Audit Logs are logged in "near" real-time and available as any other logs in GCP. You can view a summary of the audit logs for your project in the [Activity Stream](https://console.cloud.google.com/home/activity) in the Google Cloud Console. A more detailed version of the logs can found in the [Logs Viewer](https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer).

---

In some cases, you may want to use **Access Logs** instead. You most likely want to use access logs if:

- You want to track access to public objects, such as assets in a
  bucket that you've configured to be a static website.
- You want to track access to objects when the access is exclusively
  granted because of the [Access Control Lists (ACLs)](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/lists) set on the
  objects.
- You want to track changes made by the [Object Lifecycle Management](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/lifecycle)
  feature.
- You intend to use [authenticated browser downloads](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/request-endpoints#cookieauth) to access objects
  in the bucket.
- You want your logs to include latency information, or the request and
  response size of individual HTTP requests.

As opposed to audit logs, access logs aren't sent "real-time" to Stackdriver Logging but are offered in the form of CSV files, generated hourly when there is activity to report in the monitored bucket, that you can download and view.

The access logs can provide an overwhelming amount of information. You'll find [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-logs#format) a table to help you identify all the information provided in these logs.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Storage buckets are meant to serve high volumes of read requests through a variety of means.  As such, reads don't also write any additional data - that would not scale well.  If you want to record when an object gets read, you would need to have the client code reading the object to also write the current time to some persistent storage.  Or, you could force all reads through some API endpoint that performs the update manually.  In either case, you are writing code and using additional resources to store this data.